# Where is the Checksum for ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso?

Tags: 18.04

We are not seeing the ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso shasum on releases.ubuntu.com either. Now only ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso Where did the previous go and why no longer on site?

Comment: It is here http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.0/